Why is raw data not accepting the format in POSTMAN?
This is my code block where I created api using Flask and testing the same on POSTMAN.
utils.py
utils.py
import os
import base64
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.ai.documentintelligence import DocumentIntelligenceClient

def get_client():
    endpoint = "endpoint"
    api_key = "apikey"
    client = DocumentIntelligenceClient(endpoint=endpoint,credential=AzureKeyCredential(api_key))
    return client

def is_file_or_url(input_string):
    if os.path.isfile(input_string):
        return 'file'
    elif urlparse(input_string).scheme in ['http', 'https']:
        return 'url'
    else:
        return 'unknown'

def load_file_as_base64(file_obj):
    # Read the contents of the file object
    data = file_obj.read()
    # Encode the data as base64
    base64_bytes = base64.b64encode(data)
    base64_string = base64_bytes.decode('utf-8')
    return base64_string

app.py
import os
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from pathlib import Path
from azure.ai.documentintelligence.models import AnalyzeDocumentRequest
from utils import get_client, load_file_as_base64

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/extract_invoice', methods=['POST'])
def extract_invoice():
    # Get the file from the request
    file = request.files['file']

    # Create the 'temp' directory if it doesn't exist
    temp_dir = 'temp'
    if not os.path.exists(temp_dir):
        os.makedirs(temp_dir)

    # Save the file to disk
    file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, file.filename)
    file.save(file_path)
    model_id = 'prebuilt-invoice'
    doc_source = Path(file_path)

    document_ai_client = get_client()

    with open(doc_source, 'rb') as file_obj:
        file_base64 = load_file_as_base64(file_obj)

    poller = document_ai_client.begin_analyze_document(
        model_id,
        {"base64Source": file_base64},
        locale="en-US",
    )

    result = poller.result()

    # Clean up the temporary file
    os.remove(file_path)

    # Extract the invoice details
    invoice_details = []
    for document in result.documents:
        document_fields = document['fields']
        fields = document_fields.keys()

        invoice_detail = {}
        for field in fields:
            if field == 'Items':
                items_list = []
                items = document_fields[field]

                for item in items['valueArray']:
                    item_fields = item['valueObject']
                    item_dict = {}
                    for item_field in item_fields.keys():
                        value = item_fields[item_field].get('content', '')
                        item_dict[item_field] = value
                    items_list.append(item_dict)
                invoice_detail[field] = items_list
            else:
                value = document_fields[field].get('content', '')
                invoice_detail[field] = value

        invoice_details.append(invoice_detail)

    return jsonify(invoice_details)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

I tried every alternative to fix the issue but its not accepting the file/its content and giving me error: ' Incorrect format, please input the right format to import'. Additionally, I also faced the following issue: 'TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object'
This is the error I always get for this particular image only.



How to reproduce that data is not acceptable?

actually, i have created an API with document intelligence in it to extract data from various modes of files(pdf, images, and more..). when i was working with that in POSTMAN API. it gave me few errors and made some modifications which are giving me these new error of 'TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object'.

Your question only included the input data and the error result, which isn't sufficient to address your problem. Please provide a minimal reproducible example of your API server code to help us find a solution.

it seems like i m tackling the problem in the wrong way and due to the limit cannot enter the code. i will add it right away.

I updated two codes for aligning indent, can you confirm it now you need to show how to call /extract_invoice endpoint with inputs (body of x-www-form-urlencoded) and error.

thanks for updating the code. I am having inputs (body of raw data) and this is still the error.

Again you need to show a URL , x-www-form-encoded key/value, error by screen-shut of Postman.

but i will be having PDF or image files as inputs these documents are then converted to relevant bas64 strings using the load_file_as_base64 function.

Your python code is server postman screen capture is client, your screen capture is just which key value is pdf or image file name. Not a content of image or pdf. I will pointing what I am talking about.

https://i.sstatic.net/KJ26P.png this is form-data key/value example.

right now ran the same code with Body as RAW data. it is able to generate outputs for images and pdf files. I have not tested it on the other file types. but i think it is to do something with file type. I ran the code on an image which was of okay type quality i got  this error: ' KeyError  KeyError: 'valueObject'  '. so it seems the error is not in the code but in the type of file being used. thanks mannn

what kind of data needs to be added to the raw data body? how should I add data in the same as well?

Just can you capture your postman form data and error of screen capture?

i have the respective image and image of error that I am getting for it as well. I am facing the issue for this particular image only.

Thank you that is exactly looking for I want to see it.  I try it but It may take a time.

I've addressed your question by demonstrating that text can be extracted from an image and that there are no issues when calling it through Postman, even though it may not directly answer your specific question.

I realized your error is HTTP Status 500
It means the document_ai_client.begin_analyze_document() has a defect during processing.
it is not a base64 decoding or encoding issue.
I made my image decoding mock server and extracted text (key/value)
Not a direct address to your server problem but I want to show your server has a problem.
Overview

Step 1 conda demo_env environment
Download and install Anaconda3
Launching Anaconda Prompt

Create demo_env and install python
conda create --name demo_env python=3.8


Switching demo_env environment
conda activate demo_env

pip install flask easyocr


Step 2 utility.py and app.py
File tree

utility.py
import easyocr
import re

def extract_invoice_details(image_path):
    reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
    result = reader.readtext(image_path)
    full_text = '\n'.join([detection[1] for detection in result])

    patterns = {
        'Amount': r'Amount\s*;\s*\$(\d+),(\d+)',
        'Application': r'Application:\s*(.*)',
        'AID': r'AID\s*:\s*(\w+)',
        'MiD': r'MiD:\s*(\d+)',
        'TID': r'TID:\s*(\d+)',
        'Date/Time': r'Date/T\s*ime;\s*(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'
    }

    extracted_items = {}
    for key, pattern in patterns.items():
        match = re.search(pattern, full_text)
        if match:
            if key == 'Amount':
                extracted_items[key] = f"${match.group(1)}.{match.group(2)}"
            elif key == 'Date/Time':
                extracted_items[key] = match.group(1).replace(' ', '; ')
            else:
                extracted_items[key] = match.group(1)
    return extracted_items

app.py
import os
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from utility import extract_invoice_details

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/extract_invoice', methods=['POST'])
def extract_invoice():
    # Get the file from the request
    file = request.files['file']

    # Create the 'temp' directory if it doesn't exist
    temp_dir = 'temp'
    if not os.path.exists(temp_dir):
        os.makedirs(temp_dir)

    # Save the file to disk
    file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, file.filename)
    file.save(file_path)

    # Use the utility function to process the image
    invoice_details = extract_invoice_details(file_path)

    # Clean up the temporary file
    os.remove(file_path)

    return jsonify(invoice_details)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

subway.jpg
Your image to save locally.
demo.py
import easyocr
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])  # 'en' is for English, you can add other languages as needed
result = reader.readtext('subway.jpg')
for detection in result:
    print(detection[1])  # Prints out extracted text

Step 3 Extract text from subway.jpg
python demo.py


demo_v2.py
from utility import extract_invoice_details

def main():
    # Specify the path to the image file
    image_path = 'subway.jpg'
    
    # Call the function from utility.py to extract invoice details
    invoice_details = extract_invoice_details(image_path)
    
    # Print the extracted details
    print("Extracted Invoice Details:")
    for key, value in invoice_details.items():
        print(f"{key}: {value}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

This code extracts only six key/value
Extract Specific Data with Regex: Using predefined regular expressions, the script searches the aggregated text for specific pieces of information such as Amount, Application, AID, MiD, TID, and Date/Time. It formats some of these pieces for consistency and clarity before returning them.
Amount ; $12,36
Application: VISA CREDIT
AID : AO000000031010
MiD: 420429002208556
TID: 75467009
Date/T ime; 06/09/2021 12:54:29

And adjust two keys
Amount ; $12,36 ->  Amount: $12.36
Date/T ime; 06/09/2021 12:54:29  -> Date/Time: 06/09/2021; 12:54:29

python demo_v2.py


Step 4 Run Flask Server
python app.py


Step 5 API call by Postman with subway.jpg
URL
POST http://localhost:5000/extract_invoice

Body
Select Form-data
The key is file and the value is subway.jpg

Press Send button
Body of Response
{
    "AID": "AO000000031010",
    "Amount": "$12.36",
    "Application": "VISA CREDIT",
    "Date/Time": "06/09/2021; 12:54:29",
    "MiD": "420429002208556",
    "TID": "75467009"
}


Summary
I believe the issue lies with your server's internal configuration, not with the base64 encoding or Postman.

No problem,  I hope it help to your problem. Can you accept and up vote my answer?
